# Is it possible to simplify this interactive macro using \typein so it doesn't use an auxiliary macro?

Tags: tex-core, typein

I would like to allow the user to interact with the document at compilation time, for example to choose the color of hyperlinks.

For that, I created a new if and used `\typein` like in the following example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} 
\newif\ifcllinks
\newcommand\cllink{}
\typein[\cllink]{Coloried links (true or false) ?}
\csname cllinks\cllink \endcsname
\ifcllinks
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=red,citecolor=blue,filecolor=green,urlcolor=blue}
\else
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,urlcolor=black}
\fi
\begin{document}
\section{Title}\label{one}
The section \ref{one}
\end{document}
```

This works, but I'm not satisfied because of the supplementary macro `\cllink` that isn't very necessary (I think).

I try

```
\newif\ifcllinks
\csname cllinks\typein{Coloried links (true or false) ?} \endcsname
```

But this doesn't work (`missing \endcsname inserted`).

Is it possible to make it works with some TeX hackery (`\expandafter`, `\string`, …) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it isn't possible to make this work.

The content of `\csname ... \endcsname` must be fully expandable, otherwise an error is raised. However `\typein` makes an assignment and assignments are not expandable, but must be executed. No TeX hackery can change this.

So

```
\typein[\cllink]{Coloried links (true or false) ?}
\csname cllinks\cllink \endcsname
```

it as small as it gets.

You could make the macro definition local if you don't want it global:

```
\begingroup
\typein[\cllink]{Coloried links (true or false) ?}
\expandafter
\endgroup
\csname cllinks\cllink \endcsname
```

but the code wont be any shorter.

Comment: I'm disappointed… but however it's a nice answer.

Answer (score 6):

One answer is already accepted, but I am going to throw mine out there anyhow: Why insist that the user type “true” or “false”? Here is a variant that will accept any answer starting with a lower case “y” as an affirmative, anything else meaning no:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\makeatletter
\def\ask#1{\typeout{#1}%
  \begingroup \endlinechar-1 \read-1 to\answer
  \expandafter\futurelet\expandafter\answer\expandafter\@ask\answer.\@nil}
\def\@ask#1\@nil
  {\ifx y\answer\expandafter\@ask@y\else\expandafter\@ask@n\fi}
\def\@ask@y#1#2{\endgroup#1}
\def\@ask@n#1#2{\endgroup#2}
\makeatother
% demo:
\ask{Answer yes or no:}{\message{[yes]}}{\message{[no]}}
\ask{And again:}{\message{[yes]}}{\message{[no]}}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The definition is a bit longer, but here is a general mechanism for asking a yes-or-no question. For your application, you could use it as

```
\ask{colored links?}
  {\hypersetup{linkcolor=red,citecolor=blue,filecolor=green,urlcolor=blue}}
  {\hypersetup{linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,urlcolor=black}}
```

Comment: I have not even think  to that, but it's a good idea

Answer (score 1):

With shell-escape you can make "`\typein`" expandable with `\@@input "|⟨command⟩"`.

Assumes UNIX-like system with bash-like shell.

Only for academical purpose, not for any serious usage.

Of course there's also the trivial solution of using `\directlua` if it's LuaTeX (which can actually be used seriously).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} 
\newif\ifcllinks

\makeatletter
\def\zap@one@space#1 {#1}
\begingroup\expandafter\endgroup\csname cllinks%
\expandafter\zap@one@space\@@input "|echo >&2;read -p 'Coloried links (true or false) ?';echo $REPLY"\endcsname
\makeatother

\ifcllinks
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=red,citecolor=blue,filecolor=green,urlcolor=blue}
\else
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,urlcolor=black}
\fi
\begin{document}
\section{Title}\label{one}
The section \ref{one}
\end{document}
```

The `zap@one@space` is needed to delete the trailing newline which is tokenized into a space (assuming `\endlinechar=13` and `\catcode 13=5`). The `\begingroup\expandafter\endgroup` is just a convenience thing to raise an error in case the user type something other than `true` or `false`.